# fancybox open wide image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fancybox

I am using fancybox to allow my users to show pictures in full size.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'img', function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
                type: 'iframe',
                href: src,
                title: '1st title'
            }
        ], {
            padding: 0
        });
    })
});
```

However one of my images is rather wide:

[image]

Which gives the following when open in fancybox:

[image]

So can anyone tell me what i can do to make sure the image matches?

Comment: Did you want to open your fancybox with your defined width and height?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna No i dont think i did ?

Comment: You can resize your image from your popup. `<img src="" height="" width=""/>` isn't it? Also can you use `beforeload` function to set `width` and `height`.